# window.print() removing check marks from checkboxes after page prints

Tags: javascript, html

I created a checklist using `icheck` radio buttons and checkboxes. I also have a button that will print the checklist.

```
<style>
  @media print {
  #printpage {
    display: none;
  }
  #submit {
    display: none;
  }
  .noprint {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group i-checks">
            <input type="checkbox" name="poa" id="poa" />
            <strong><a href="forms/poa.cfm" target="_blank">Power of Attorney - if applicable (click here to print)</a></strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <button class="btn-u btn-u-orange"  onclick="printChecklist()" name="printpage" id="printpage" ><i class="icon-printer"></i> Print Checklist</button>

    <script>
    function printChecklist() {
        window.print();
    }
    </script>
```

> The issue I am running into is once I select print all the check boxes then becoming unchecked again as if the page has refreshed or something.

Is there a way for my button to print the page but not uncheck all of my checkboxes leaving the screen just the way the user left it as they hit the print button?

Comment: which browser? i cannot repeat it in chrome

Comment: I am in chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: is there bootstrap? which version?

Comment: https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/issues/125

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184827/discussion-between-slavik-and-david-brierton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one else runs into this issue that I had. What I finally found was I removed the script function and changed the onclick for the button to `onclick="window.print(); return false;"`